# 3D interpolation with irregular values of x,y and z

Tags: matlab

I have few values `X`, `Y` and `Z`. And corresponding to these values I have a value `B`.
Now I have file with `Xi`, `Yi` and `Zi` values. But the values corresponding to this is what I need to fill.

My question looks similar to many examples of interpolation.
But I had never implemented this in any of the language.

`interp3` function is available in MATLAB.
I believe this will solve my problem.
But I am unable to come through this.

I will be wishing for a working code.
Even a python code will help.
Kindly help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) rather than `interp3`

```
 Bi = griddata( X, Y, Z, B, Xi, Yi, Zi );
```

Comment: i will kill myself if what you say is right :)
I hope this is the right answer.

Comment: @Shrey - No need to kill yourself in the name of MATLAB.  A thank you to Shai is totally fine.

Comment: What if someone would like to find Xi instead of Bi? Would using Xi = griddata(B, Y, Z, X, Bi, Yi, Zi); works?

Comment: @m_power why not? it's only variable names... `b=f(x,y,z)` is the same as `x=g(b,y,z)` for some `f` and `g`... as long as there is such `g(...)`

Comment: @Shai Its clearly not working for me. Something is probably wrong with my variable dimensions as I'm getting NaN as an answer (even if I'm able to get the correct answer from 3 calls to interp1).

Comment: @m_power Nan's usually means you are extrapolating

Comment: @m_power but clearly you have some problem. why don't you post it as a new question?